# I am getting this error "TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)" at "client_response" variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sockets, websocket

EDIT to format:

This is the original code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import socket
import sys

def socket_accept():
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print("Connection has been established | " + "IP " + address[0] + "| Port " + str(address[1]))
    send_commands(conn)
    conn.close()

def send_commands(conn):
    while True:
        cmd = raw_input()
        if cmd == 'quit':
            conn.close()
            s.close()
            sys.exit()
        if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
            conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
            client_response = str(conn.recv(1024), "utf-8")
            print(client_response, end ="")

def main():
    socket_accept()
    main()
```

I am getting this error “TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)” at “client_response” variable

Comment: Please format your code and explain what you are trying to do and what is the expected result.

Comment: Okay doing it now

Answer (score 21):

You have your error here:

```
client_response = str(conn.recv(1024), "utf-8")
```

Just change it to:

```
client_response = str(conn.recv(1024)).encode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 7):

On the second to last line you're passing two arguments to the `str` function, although the `str` function only takes a single argument in Python 2. It does in fact take up to three arguments in python 3

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=str#str
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=str#str

So you're either trying to inadvertaetly run python 3 code in a python 2 interpreter or you're looking at the wrong language documentation.

So either use @franciscosolimas's answer, if you're using python 2, or make sure you're using python 3, if the latter you might also want to add a keyword argument just to make sure you know what's happening in the future

```
client_response = str(conn.recv(1024), encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

## 3 arguments, 5 given

I got a similar error, may not be the same here (as the op) but, it was simple enough fix and wanted to share, since I ended up here from my searches on the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "queries.py", line 50, in <module>
"WHERE ao.type='u';")
TypeError: str() takes at most 3 arguments (5 given)`
```

> What fixed it for me in `python3` was converting my `,`'s to `+`

### Error:

```
str("SELECT s.name + '.' + ao.name, s.name"
            "FROM sys.all_objects ao",
            "INNER JOIN sys.schemas s",
            "ON s.schema_id = ao.schema_id",
            "WHERE ao.type='u';"))
```

### Fixed:

```
str("SELECT s.name + '.' + ao.name, s.name " +
            "FROM sys.all_objects ao " +
            "INNER JOIN sys.schemas s " +
            "ON s.schema_id = ao.schema_id " +
            "WHERE ao.type='u';")
```

I had to add my own spaces so the `passed` query would work.
As the commas were doing that in python...

Thoughts & my educated guess:
looks like in my case it got caught up trying to evaluate in bash/python a litteral `u'`

To my knowledge this break could be in bash because there is no command called `u` and/or in python `u'` is you trying to `unicode` an incomplete string. Either way it broke and wanted to share my fix.

Cheers!

~JayRizzo