# How to loop over a file and delete parts of the file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data structure such as following.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<corpus name="corpus">
  <recording audio="audio.wav" name="first audio">
    <segment name="1" start="0" end="2">
        <orth>some text 1</orth>
    </segment>
    <segment name="2" start="2" end="4">
        <orth>some text 2</orth>
    </segment>
    <segment name="3" start="4" end="6">
        <orth>some text 3</orth>
    </segment>
  </recording>
</corpus>
```

given an input file containing number of files such as

```
1
3
```

it would remove the segments that has those `name`. For example, 1 and 3 was given so segments with names 1 and 3 has been removed.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<corpus name="corpus">
  <recording audio="audio.wav" name="first audio">
    <segment name="2" start="2" end="4">
        <orth>some text 2</orth>
    </segment>
  </recording>
</corpus>
```

the code I have so far

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as inputFile:
    w_file = inputFile.readlines()

w_file = w_file.strip('\n')

with open('to_delete_nums.txt', 'r') as File:
    d_file = deleteFile.readlines()

d_file = d_file.strip('\n')

for line in w_file:
    if line.contains("<segment name"):
        for d in d_file:
            //if segment name is equal to d then delete that segment.
```

How do I accomplish this? I also think having 2 might be unnecessary is that correct?

Comment: Why not use an XML parsing/manipulation library?

Comment: what exactly output you want to get please give that data

Comment: better use `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` to parse `XML` and works with elements in tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1 (with a module):

Just like [@iain-shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington) said with a XML parsing/manipulation library You can do it simply and fast;

Try this with [**lxml**](https://lxml.de/) module and [**xpath**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

```
import lxml.etree as et

xml = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<corpus name="corpus">
  <recording audio="audio.wav" name="first audio">
    <segment name="1" start="0" end="2">
        <orth>some text 1</orth>
    </segment>
    <segment name="2" start="2" end="4">
        <orth>some text 2</orth>
    </segment>
    <segment name="3" start="4" end="6">
        <orth>some text 3</orth>
    </segment>
  </recording>
</corpus>"""
tree = et.XML(xml.encode())
find_segments = tree.xpath("*//segment[@name='1' or @name='2']") # you can add more segments here

for each_segment in find_segments:
    each_segment.getparent().remove(each_segment)

clean_content = str(et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True), encoding="utf-8")
print(clean_content)
```

Some credits to [@cédric-julien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718618/c%C3%A9dric-julien), [@Sheena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/742082/sheena), [@xyz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/705773/xyz), [@josh-allemon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2594088/josh-allemon) and these questions:

1. [how to remove an element in lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981840/how-to-remove-an-element-in-lxml)
2. [Using an OR condition in Xpath to identify the same element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523638/using-an-or-condition-in-xpath-to-identify-the-same-element)
3. [lxml.etree.XML ValueError for Unicode string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534460/lxml-etree-xml-valueerror-for-unicode-string)

### Method 2 (Hard Code):

```
xml = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<corpus name="corpus">
  <recording audio="audio.wav" name="first audio">
    <segment name="1" start="0" end="2">
        <orth>some text 1</orth>
    </segment>
    <segment name="2" start="2" end="4">
        <orth>some text 2</orth>
    </segment>
    <segment name="3" start="4" end="6">
        <orth>some text 3</orth>
    </segment>
  </recording>
</corpus>"""

lines = []
toggle = True
for each_line in xml.splitlines():
    if each_line.strip().startswith("<segment") and ('name="1"' in each_line or 'name="2"' in each_line):
        toggle = False
    elif each_line.strip().startswith("</segment>") and toggle is False:
        toggle = True
    elif toggle:
        lines.append(each_line)

new_xml = "\n".join(lines)
print(new_xml)
```

**If you want to read names from file then try this:**

```
from lxml import etree

with open("xml.txt", "r") as xml_file:
    xml_data = xml_file.read()

with open('nums.txt', 'r') as file:
    list_of_names = file.read().split("\n")

new_xml = xml_data
for each_name in list_of_names:
    tree = etree.XML(new_xml.encode())
    find_segments = tree.xpath("*//segment[@name='{}']".format(each_name))
    for each_segment in find_segments:
        each_segment.getparent().remove(each_segment)
    new_xml = str(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True), encoding="utf-8")

print(new_xml)
```

**Much Shorter:**

```
from lxml import etree

with open("xml.txt", "r") as xml_file:
    tree = etree.XML(xml_file.read().encode())

with open('nums.txt', 'r') as file:
    list_of_names = list(set(file.read().split("\n")))

xpath = "*//segment[{}]".format(" or ".join(["@name='{}'".format(each_name) for each_name in list_of_names]))

print(xpath)
for each_segment in tree.xpath(xpath):
    each_segment.getparent().remove(each_segment)
new_xml = str(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True), encoding="utf-8")

print(new_xml)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! ```@name='1' or @name='2'``` seems like it would be a lot of manual input. Is there a way to automatically read those from a file? In the question, I say that there is already a file containing the names one per line.

Comment: @JosephKars; yes wait i will write it.

Comment: @JosephKars; check my update and notify me

Comment: @JosephKars: updated check again. this one is much shorter than that

Comment: Using your last code, I got ```TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)```

Comment: ```*//segment[@name='1' or @name='' or @name='3']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "del_bad_segs.py", line 14, in <module>
    new_xml = str(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True), encoding="utf-8")
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)```

Comment: @JosephKars: You are on python 2.x right? python3.x str function has 2 arguments but in 2.x it has 1 argument. so just remove the comma and encoding="utf-8" from string and use this: str(x).encode("utf-8")... which x is the previous first argument. notify me....

Comment: @JosephKars: see the first line of your error message: look ate second name... its empty...do you have some errors in your file ? empty lines ?

Comment: @JosephKars; if it worked or not notify me

Comment: I do not have empty lines and I am using python 3. it appears that using str() to handle this is not ideal. I will accepty your answer regardless. Thank you!

Comment: @JosephKars Tnx YW; Are you sure about your python version? because see the error message TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given); as i know python3 will not show this error. check this answer about str function and its arguments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346984/i-am-getting-this-error-typeerror-str-takes-at-most-1-argument-2-given-at/42347165

Comment: Sorry! misclick yes i'm on python2. Sorry for the confusion. I tried your solution. I am getting ```UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position```

Comment: @JosephKars: replace this and notify me: `new_xml = etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True).decode("utf-8")`

Comment: I got ```UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 306-307: ordinal not in range(128)```

Comment: @JosephKars add "ignore" argument and try again: new_xml = etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True).decode("utf-8", "ignore")

Comment: ```File "del_bad_segs.py", line 13, in <module>
    tree = etree.XML(new_xml.encode())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 306-307: ordinal not in range(128)``` I got this.

Comment: @JosephKars: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765614/lxml-encoding-error-when-parsing-utf8-xml and notify me

Comment: @JosephKars: how much the size of your xml file ? you can upload it i can check and write code for do correction. God willing